# Clarification requested: Surface integrals, functions defined on surfaces and dimension

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Surface integrals were always confusing for me, mainly because I never studied them carefully and in depth. After some research on several sources (not sufficient enough) I came across with the following questions/statements which I would highly appreciate if someone could explain/verify.

Let's consider the unit sphere $\mathbb S^2=\{(x,y,z):\;x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$.

1. A function $f$ defined on $\mathbb S^2$ is, in general, a function of $3-$variables.
2. The surface integral $\int_{\mathbb S^2} f\;dS$ though, can be calculated with an appropriate parametrization as a double integral (with respect to $2-$coordinates). **Is this correct?** If yes, then how is this justified?
3. Assume now that $f$ is a function defined on $\mathbb S^2$ as before but depends only on variable $x$. If I want to integrate $f$ over the set $\{x>x_0\}$, how would this integral look like? I've seen this formula

> $\int_{\{x>x_0\}} f\;dS=2\pi \int_{x_0}^1 f(x)\;dx$

which implies (if not mistaken) that there was some extra integration from $0$ to $2\pi$ that resulted in the $2\pi$ factor but I can't understand how this came up. I tried to use cylindrical coordinates but I don't obtain the desired formula.

I'm having a really hard time getting my head around these notions and arguments. Any help, hint or comments are very much welcome.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The 2-sphere is a 2 dimensional manifold by nature; though $f$ may be superficially represented in terms of three variables, there is actually hidden redundancy here. If the x and y coordinate were known (or more appropriately, the polar angle and azimuthal angle), then the remaining component could be determined from the equation of S2. This is the reason why a surface integral over S2 is reduced to a double integral. Your 3rd question is more complicated, though

Comment: @RobBland you mean since I can write $z=\sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)}$ then at the end I only work with $x,y$ variables... hmm ok! thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f : \mathbb S^2 \to \mathbb R$ is a function which only depends on the $x$ component of the input point. To compute $\int_{x>x_0} f\ dS$, let us first describe a parametrization of $\mathbb S^2$ to fit our purposes.

Suppose $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb S^2$ and $x = x_0$ is fixed. Then $(y,z)$ lies on a circle in the $yz$-plane of radius $r_x = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$, and thus both $y$ and $z$ can be specified by a single angle $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$.

We thus have a coordinate system/a parametrization of the unit sphere, given by \begin{align*}
&x = x \\
&y = r_x\cos \theta \\
&z = r_x\sin \theta
\end{align*} for $-1 < x < 1$, and $0 < \theta < 2\pi$. The jacobian of this transformation is given by $||(1,r_x^\prime \cos \theta,r_x^\prime \sin \theta) \times (0, -r_x \sin \theta, r_x \cos \theta)|| = 1$ (amazingly), therefore \begin{align*}
\int_{x > x_0} f(x)\ dS &= \iint_R f(x)\ d\theta dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_{x_0}^1 f(x)\ dx
\end{align*} Where $R = \{ 0 < \theta < 2\pi, \; x_0 < x < 1\}$

Comment: "A function f on $S^2$ is, in general, a function of three variables".   But NOT three *independent* variables.  $S^2$, the unit sphere centered at the origin can be given , in a Cartesian coordinate system, as $x^2+ y^2+ z^2= 1$ so $f(x, y, z)= f(x, y, \pm\sqrt{1- x^2- y^2})$.  Or, in spherical coordinates, since the radius is the constant, 1, $x= r cos(\theta) sin(\phi)= cos(theta)sin(\phi)$, $y= r sin(\theta)sin(\phi)= sin(\theta)sin(\phi)$, $z= r cos(\phi)= cos(\phi)$.  Really just two *independent* variables.

Comment: @Rob Bland Ok, so although I had in mind that the whole time $r=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ when I computed the Jacobian I totally missed it! I am just silly! Thank you very very much! Could I ask something more? Do you have any good reference for surface integrals ?